# Homotopy Types of Fibrations in Postnikov Tower encoded by Classifing map

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, classifying-spaces

A [Postnikov system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postnikov_system) of a path-connected space $X$  is an inverse system of spaces

$$  \cdots \to X_{n}\xrightarrow {p_{n}} X_{n-1}\xrightarrow {p_{n-1}} \cdots \xrightarrow {p_{3}} X_{2}\xrightarrow {p_{2}} X_{1}\xrightarrow {p_{1}} \{*\} $$

with a sequence of maps $ \phi _{n}\colon X\to X_{n}$ compatible with the inverse system such that

1. The map $ \phi _{n}\colon X\to X_{n}$ induces an isomorphism $ \pi _{i}(X)\to \pi _{i}(X_{n})$ for every $ i\leq n$.
2. $ \pi _{i}(X_{n})=0 $ for $ i>n$ .
3. Each map $ \displaystyle p_{n}\colon X_{n}\to X_{n-1}$  is a *fibration*, with homotopy fiber $F_{n} $, which is the Eilenberg–MacLane space, $ K(\pi _{n}(X),n)$.

The first two conditions imply that $ \displaystyle X_{1}$ is also a $ K(\pi _{1}(X),1)$-space. More generally, if $\displaystyle X$ is $(n-1)$-connected, then $  X_{n}$  is a $  K(\pi _{n}(X),n)$-space and all $ X_{i} $ for $ i<n $ are contractible.

continuing in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postnikov_system#Homotopy_classification_of_fibrations) is moreover stated that the homotopy class of fibration $p_n:X_n \to X_{n+1} $ comes from homotopy class of the classifying map for the fiber $  K(\pi _{n}(X),n)$. Why? I not see at this point any direct connection. How the homotopy class of $p_n$ can be constructed resp. related to certain class of a classifying map

$$   X_{n-1} \to  B(K(\pi _{n}(X),n)) \simeq K(\pi _{n}(X),n+1)   $$

as clamed in wikipedia? In other words why the homotopy class of $p_n$ can be considered as a homotopy class in $[X_{n-1},B(K(\pi _{n}(X),n))]$? Could somebody unravel where this identification comes from?

Comment: The maps $X_{n-1} \to K(\pi_n, n+1)$ are known as the $k$-invariants of the space. The construction is explained in detail in Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) book, pg. 411-412.

Comment: @ChesterX: so far I can follow Hatcher these invariants are not always defined (only in case the fibration $p_n:X_n \to X_{n+1}$ is **principal**, right? So it's simply wrong what wikipedia says that these fibrations $p_n$ admit *always* such invariants?

Comment: Well, technically yes! The $k$-invariants make sense when the fibrations are principal. But the thing is you can always get a Postnikov tower so that the fibrations are indeed principal. In fact, there is a functorial choice of a Postnikov system where everything fits together nicely. I would recommend also having a look at Whitehead's Element of Homotopy Theory, Ch. IX.

Comment: @ChesterX: What do you mean precisely when you say that one can always get a Postnikov tower so that the fibrations are indeed principal? Do you mean by this that for *every* path-connected space $X$ there *exist* a principal Postnikov tower $X_* \to X$?  And if there is another principal Postnikov tower $X'_* \to X$ the sets of $k$-invariants coincide, right? (That's what you mean by *functorial*?)

Comment: Yes, this is Theorem 4.69 in Hatcher's book. There are some mild conditions that you need to assume on the space. For example, a simply connected CW complex will always admit a Postnikov system of principal fibrations.

Comment: You mean the triviality of the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on all $\pi_n(X), n >2$? Do you maybe know if there is a generalization to define the $k$-invariant in similar manner for a broader class of CW complexes or even more general spaces with possibly "more complicated" $k$-invariants as"the price to pay" for discarding this condition on triviality of $\pi_1(X)$-action? I'm asking this because in the wikipedia link is nothing said about this restrictive condition so I was wondering if these invariants can be defined more generally

Comment: The triviality of the action is a necessary and sufficient condition according to Hatcher. This is obviously satisfied when $\pi_1(X) = 0$. You can still define $k$-invariants for more general spaces, as explained in Pg. 423 of Whitehead's book, but I am not sure if the author is tacitly assuming any extra condition on the space there.